# Disposing thrift client - remote side closed exception

Tags: c#, soa, thrift

When I put my thrift client reference in a using block I get a TTransportException : "Cannot read, Remote side has closed exception."

```
//THRIFT IDL
namespace csharp ReferenceData.API

exception EntityDoesNotExistException {
    1: string Key;  
}

service ReferenceDataService {
    bool HelloWorld() throws (1: EntityDoesNotExistException entityDoesNotExistException);
}

namespace Server
{
    public class Service: ReferenceDataService.Iface
    {
        public bool HelloWorld()
        {
            throw new EntityDoesNotExistException(){Key = "TEST KEY"};
        }
    }
}

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var processor = new ReferenceData.API.ReferenceDataService.Processor(new Service());
                TServerTransport serverTransport = new TServerSocket(9094);
                TServer server = new TThreadedServer(processor, serverTransport);
                Console.WriteLine("Running the Payroll Service on port {0}...", "9094");
                server.Serve();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(x.StackTrace);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}


namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var transport = new Thrift.Transport.TSocket("127.0.0.1", 9094);
            transport.Open();
            var service = new ReferenceDataService.Client(new Thrift.Protocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)); 

            using (service)
            {
                try
                {
                    service.HelloWorld();
                }
                catch (EntityDoesNotExistException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Key);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The remote method call actually succeeds but I have observed that the Processor.Process method is called twice and it is the second call that triggers the exception.  Should the Process method be called twice? Should I be explicitly calling Dispose like this, I assumed that I should in order to close the socket as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is by design.

The `Process()` method is called until the connection ends, typically because the client disconnects. In that case, `ReadMessageBegin()` fails with this exception which is expected and caught in [TThreadedServer.cs](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob_plain;f=lib/csharp/src/Server/TThreadedServer.cs;hb=HEAD), right below the `Process()` loop.

For the curious: The exception is [thrown in `TTransport.ReadAll()`](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob_plain;f=lib/csharp/src/Transport/TTransport.cs;hb=HEAD)